# HSK6的第101题（缩写）请求反馈：富有爸爸和会花钱的儿子

Tags: writing-critique, hsk

我在练习HSK6里的第101题：缩写。我用了[这个过去的考卷](https://www.guancha.cn/LiYe/2015_05_06_318487_2.shtml)练习，而下面是我的写作（[原始版](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlyT1.jpg)）。我不可以用电脑、词典什么的，也作文400字数限制。据[这个课程](https://www.coursera.org/learn/chinese-for-hsk-6/lecture/g5u7g/zhi-shi-yu-ji-neng-di-20ke)里的评论，我必须包括分段。

关于下面的写作，**我请求反馈**，想知道我最重要的缺点。我特别想知道前HSK6的学生的建议。（据我目前的知识，[没有网站提供正确答案的例子](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/questions/4750/where-can-i-find-example-answers-to-the-chinese-hsk6-test-composition-%e4%b9%a6%e5%86%99-aka-%e7%bc%a9%e5%86%99)。）

> 儿子只有**自由**才能成功
>
> 有钱的父亲担心他粗心花钱的儿子，虽然他劝儿子该负责自己，而不总是靠爸爸的**富财**，儿子还享受他生活方式。因此父亲告诉儿子他被破产了。儿子发现了他没有自己的能力、朋友和当时的女朋友都只喜欢他的钱。这令儿子惊**牙**，他甚至**式企**自杀不过父亲阻止他，又劝他成为**自由**的人。
>
> 这次儿子听爸爸，所以他去在爸爸好友的公司工作，那个人是林先生。在林先生的**训教**下，儿子逐渐取得成功，交到了新朋友以及娶得尊重他的妻子。
>
> 他老爸去去世以前脸上有可见的满足感，他也给儿子一封信告诉儿子他不是真的破产，而其实他不得已用这种方法使儿子更了解**自由**的价值。他父爱绝对相信**自由**的儿子能一辈子中获得成功。

我自己已经发现一些错误：（1）“自由”应该换成“独立”、（2）是“财富”不是“富财“，而且我“财”写的不对、（3）是“惊讶”不是“惊牙”、（4）“式企”应该是“企图”、（5）“训教”应该是“指导”、（6）我应该加一个“被”和两个“了”（看图片）。

> [image: 原始版，小图]

Answer (score 2):

*我没有参加过这类考试, 且离开学校很久了, 所以我的建议未必适合你, 不过这是我的看法, 供参考.*

**题目要求不能有自己的观点**

所以--*儿子只有自由才能成功*--这个观点应该删掉: , 这个句子的语法也有问题, 应该把"儿子"删掉, *只有自由才能成功*, 否则会有父亲就不需要自由嘛这种感觉. 这个观点本身也有争议, 可能有人在监狱里关了一辈子, 但仍然成功了, 所以不能加上"只有".

下面是我改的

> 有钱的父亲担心他儿子乱花钱，常劝儿子该为自己负责，而不能总是靠爸爸的财富。有一天, 父亲告诉儿子他破产了。
>
> 这次儿子听了父亲的话，去了他父亲好友的公司，那个人是林先生。在林先生的训教下，儿子当上了总经理，娶了贤惠的妻子。
>
> 他老爸临终时脸上浮现了欣慰的样子，他留给儿子一封信, 告诉儿子他不是真的破产，而是用这种方法激励儿子.

下面我写的, 希望有帮助.

> 一个父亲是赚钱高手, 他总担心他的儿子花钱大手大脚，因此常常劝他. 儿子却听不进去. 直到有一天, 父亲告诉儿子他破产了. 儿子不得不自力更生.

> 父亲介绍儿子去了朋友--林先生的公司. 工作很辛苦, 不过儿子还是坚持了下来, 他当上了总经理, 还娶了一个贤惠的太太.

> 突然, 父亲病倒了. 儿子从父亲的律师那里知道, 父亲原来没有破产. 父亲的遗嘱里写到, 他的一半财产给林先生,条件是林先生要培养儿子成才, 另一半留给儿子.

> 儿子还收到父亲的一封信, 信里父亲告诉儿子, 他要用他全部家当换儿子成才.

Answer (score 2):

> 儿子只有自由才能成功 --> 儿子只有独立才能成功

> you found the mistake already

~

> 有钱的父亲担心他粗心花钱的儿子，--> 有钱的父亲担心他胡亂花钱的儿子，

> both 粗心 and 胡亂 can means careless. but 粗心 implies naive or innocent , 胡亂 implies unwisely and casually, which is a better choice. One of your weakness is word choice. I suggest you check your words often , see if a better choice is available or needed. (I suppose it was how you found out 独立 is better choice than 自由 in this writing. Just keep doing it)

~

> 虽然他劝儿子该负责自己，而不总是靠爸爸的富财，--> 虽然他劝儿子该對自己负责，而不是总靠爸爸的财富

> 负责 means "Be responsible for" and it is usually following by a task, not an object. 儿子该负责自己 = the son should be responsible for himself ; 儿子该對自己负责 = the son should be accountable to himself

> here is another weakness, you still haven't been fully proficient on matching verb with object. For that, there's no quick fix. The only thing you can do is to write more, get corrected, then write some more

~

> 儿子还享受他生活方式。因此父亲告诉儿子他被破产了。--> 儿子(仍然)享受他(的)生活方式。因此父亲告诉儿子他破产了。

> 还 can mean 'still', but it can also mean 'also'. therefore, "还是" (still)  would be the correct choice because it specifically mean 'still'. It is another example of narrow word choice. The fix is as the first suggestion I gave

> 被破产了 is wrong, it should be 破产了 (intransitive verb); same case as you can only 自殺了, not 被自殺了. To avoid the same mistake, translate the verb to English to see if it is transitive or intransitive

The problems in the rest of the writing are more or less the same

Edit:

Tips I had mentioned in your posts before -- Omit everything you can omit is considered good writing (avoid wordiness). Break up long sentence with commas help reducing errors (easier to spot)

Answer (score 2):

你的写作我先不评阅，我跟你分享一下我的经验。

我是 7 年以前考过的 HSK6。每一项考题的具体成绩，我已经不记得了，不过我刚考完后就觉得我写作写得挺差！结果，我居然得了高分了。

当时我写的整体看起来相当简陋，罕见的字也没用上，句子结构不复杂，我以为无法达到适合HSK6的标准。

不过，在我看来，对于考生来说写作为最难的一题，我估计审阅考卷的老师也知道，他们的实际要求比学生想象中的低一点。

因此呢，只要你写的内容符合逻辑，用语无误，句型淡雅，言简意赅，应该没有什么问题。

Comment: If Chinese is your second language, then your Chinese is very impressive, at least your writing is really good(judging from what you wrote above). Only problem I found in your writing here is "在我看法中".  The more idiomatic way to express it is 在我看来.